# CircleCI suddenly stopped building task

Tags: circleci

CircleCI suddenly stopped building task, but I couldn't get the reason and how to fix it. The error message is below.

```
Your build was not run - reason code (:org-over-credit-limit).
```

Comment: do you have some plan with them?

Comment: Ours is unpaid plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into the same problem when we were using Circleci 1.0. We switched our build to Circleci 2.0 and our builds started running again.